# How to achieve two-column layout without calc?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the layout similar to the following

[image]

The left and right are adaptive, fixed in the middle。

without calc。

thanks， my english is not good.

example：https://jsbin.com/qajiqi/edit?html,css,output

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="button" value="left" class="left">
  <input type="button" value="right" class="right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndyamkxc/) is what I came up with.

I used flexbox, which at once takes care of element width and floating. You can read a handy guide on it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or by Googling "flexbox".

Specifically, I made the `.wrap` into a flexbox using `display: flex;`. I also made sure that the buttons would not become too high by using`align-items: flex-start;`. You can try removing it to see what happens, or read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items). I made the width 50% and added a margin to each of them. The flexbox takes care of sizing for you.